# Are there any more Vampire the Requiem Novels?

Tags: chronicles-of-darkness-1e, vampire-the-requiem

The only 3 novels for VtR that I am aware of are:

1. A Hunger Like Fire
2. Blood In, Blood Out
3. Marriage of Virtue & Viciousness

Does anyone know of any others?  If not, does anyone know if there are any plans by White Wolf to create more?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it does not appear to be about role-playing games within the scope defined in the [help center](/help/on-topic), and because [questions in the vein of "Does X exist?" are a poor fit for the Stack Exchange format](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6052/33569).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

White Wolf halted their fiction line a couple years back.  I believe they are starting to release some new fiction via PDF/POD thru DriveThruRPG.

Answer (score 4):

I just found newer Requiem books on:
http://www.drivethrufiction.com/browse.php?cPath=9531

"Silent knife" by David Nurenberg looks like a new novel.
(I am not sure about the others except the 4 mentioned above.)

Answer (score 2):

The events in those three novels are continued or concluded in game fiction (also written by Greg Stolze) in the **Danse Macabre** sourcebook.

Answer (score -1):

While not strictly in the series, there is a 4th book called *Three Shades of Night*.

However, Amazon has some books which are called "clan books" which apparently read like a novel.

http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias%3Dstripbooks&field-keywords=Vampire+the+Requiem&x=0&y=0#/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias%3Dstripbooks&field-keywords=Vampire+the+Requiem+novel&rh=n%3A283155%2Ck%3AVampire+the+Requiem+novel

Comment: The Requiem clanbooks don't read anything like novels. They're one-half in-character diary entries, one-quarter obscure ephemera, and one quarter "crunch": game mechanics and new play elements. Reading them straight is likely to be confusing and disappointing.

Comment: Heh, well one of the reviewers really like the diary entries then! (it came up in a search for novel)